# Found footage movie where teens get superpowers after getting struck by lightning?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember small pieces of the plot, from them getting struck by lightning, testing out their powers, and floating down while doing backflips in the air.

One of the teens goes a bit crazy, as he starts robbing stores and uses his powers to hold the camera. One of the other guys goes to confront him in the air, but he dies after getting struck again.

Then the swat or military get involved, with the crazy one flinging bullets back at them, the two remaining teens get into a fight, with the crazy one dying as the movie ends with the last one hiking in the Himalayan mountains with the camera.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This sounds like *Chronicle* (2012):

> Chronicle is a 2012 American **found footage** superhero thriller film directed by Josh Trank with a screenplay by Max Landis from a story they both co-wrote. It follows three Seattle high school seniors, bullied Andrew (Dane DeHaan), his cousin Matt (Alex Russell), and more popular Steve (Michael B. Jordan), who form a bond after gaining telekinetic powers from an unknown object and using them for fun, although Andrew begins going down a darker path.
>
> [...]
>
> Due to the incident at the party as well as Steve's death, Andrew's relationship with Matt grows strained and he is once again ostracized at school. After using his powers to rip teeth out of a bully's mouth in front of a crowd of other students when he is taunted about the party, **Andrew begins to identify as an apex predator and rationalizes that he should not feel guilty for using his powers to hurt those weaker than him.** Desperate to pay for his mother's medication, Andrew disguises himself with his father's firefighter gear and uses his powers to steal money. **While robbing a gas station,** he inadvertently causes an explosion that puts him in the hospital. At his bedside, a distraught Richard informs an unconscious Andrew that Karen has died and angrily blames Andrew for her death. As his father is about to strike him, Andrew awakens and abruptly grabs his arm before blowing out the wall of the room.
>
> [...]
>
> Some time later, Matt lands in Tibet with Andrew's camera, tearfully apologizing to him and vowing to use his powers for good and find out what happened to them. **He points the camera at a Tibetan monastery in the distance before flying away, leaving the camera behind.**
>
> <sub>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicle_(film), emphasis added</sub>